# Storing arbitrary attributes on tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, `x`, `y`, and `z`. I want to be able to attach arbitrary
attributes to each row in each table. `x`, `y`, and `z` have nothing in
common other than the fact that they all have an integer primary key called
`id` and should be able to have arbitrary attributes attached to them.

Is it better to make a single attributes table, like

```
create table attributes (
    table enum('x', 'y', 'z'),
    xyz_id integer,
    name varchar(50),
    value text,
    primary key (table, xyz_id, name)
);
```

Or is it best to make separate tables, like

```
create table x_attributes (
    x_id integer,
    name varchar(50),
    value text,
    primary key (x_id, name),
    foreign key (x_id) references x (id)
);
create table y_attributes (...);
create table z_attributes (...);
```

The second option (separate tables) seems to be cleaner, but requires a lot
more boilerplate on both the database side and the application side.

I'm also open to suggestions other than those two.

*Note: I've considered the possibility of using a document store like MongoDB, but
the data I'm working with is fundamentally relational.*

Answer (score 0):

Go with one table with an enum column, it will make grabbing all of the attributes for each row easier in the long run.

Comment: Sprinkle some partitioning in, if your RDBMS supports it.  Shard it by hand if not.